# Null pointer exception when adding TextView

Tags: java, android

I have a ScrollView, and I'm trying to add TextViews to the LinearLayout in it but i keep getting an error.

```
TextView l = new TextView(StopWatch.this);
l.setText("Didn't work");
l.setTextSize(20);
llLocations.addView(l);
```

I was trying to use this code to see if the ArrayList i was using was empty, but it wasnt that. It says the error is caused by a NullPointerException at...

```
llLocations.addView(l);
```

I have other code that does the same thing, and i tried comparing them but there wasn't a difference so i'm confused. How do i fix this?

```
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     ... 11 more
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     at com.TBJsoft.runprogress.StopWatch.done(StopWatch.java:506)
07-10 21:14:42.687: E/AndroidRuntime(5241):     ... 14 more
```

StopWath.java:506 is the

```
llLocations.addView(l);
```

line.

I'm trying to do this in an alert dialog that has a custom view with the scroll view in it. Do you think that could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`llLocations` is null. [Read](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) up on `findViewById`. The end.

Comment: Well, (s)he could always show the rest of the code where llLocations is initialized... anyway, maybe Dalvik just is allergic to hungarian notation

Comment: llLocations = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llLocations); I have this in the onCreate mehtod

Comment: Really? Now you tell me. Either the stack trace is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

llLocations is null , so I guess you did something like that:

```
LinearLayout llLocations = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.<here_the_id_of_the_linearleayout_in_your_xml_layout>);
```

If you did this, and the id is the correct one, and you setContentView of your activity with this layout which contains the linearlayout, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

normally you have to bind the `TextView` to an id!
Like that:

```
example = findViewById(R.id.yourid);
```

For your own knowledge, R is dynamically generated by android out of your values-file(IDs are mostly assigned in the layout-files)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable which is an instance of a class, you need to initialize it. If you do not initialize it, it will have a null pointer.

llocations was not initialized properly before you try to access its method. But you cannot access the method of a null pointer, right? It would be like shaking hands with nobody. So, this is an exceptional behavior and that is why the NullPointerException is thrown.